# How to remove unnecessary indentation guides in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to remove the indentation lines that are marked in red as they serve no purpose. I want to make the indentation of 1 tab = 4 spaces, but VSCode automatically made it as 1 tab = 2 spaces. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I want to remove the indentation lines that are marked in red as they serve no purpose.

```
File->Preference->Settings and search for "renderIndentGuides". 

uncheck    Editor: Render Indent Guides
```

I want to make the indentation of 1 tab = 4 spaces, but VSCode automatically made it as 1 tab = 2 spaces.

```
Gotto 
File->Prefrences->setting -> Detect Indentation -> Click editor:TabSize 
Here you can update to 4
```